# Can I drive LEDs through an FFC cable with only one ground wire?

Tags: led, ground, emc, led-driver, ffc

I am working on a redesign of a device which currently works as is, and passed the EMC certification. I have a question about the modification I am planning to integrate.

Here is the setup : on board #1, there are 5 constant-current LED drivers (**MP3306EG-LF-P-Z**), each one drives a branch of two LEDs. The LEDs are high-current LEDs (approx. 500 mA), they are on board #2. The connection between the two boards is a FFC cable. Here is the schematics with just 2 LED drivers:

[image]

Board #2 is an IMS board, there is only one layer of copper. Here is the layout:

[image]

On board #1, all the "cathode" parts of the branches go into a ground plane, but on board #2, I cannot have a ground plane, so all the grounds traces are wired. Thus in the FFC cable, each branch requires 2 wires.

The redesign involves adding components on board #2. To do this, I am planning to group all the grounds of the LED on board #2, so that the return current of the 5 LEDs only requires 1 wire instead of 5:
[image]

- Could this redesign degrade the control of the LEDs?
- Could this lead to EMI problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that about how much current the FFC cable wire or connector can handle? You never say which cable or connector you will use so we can't say if it is good for 500mA or not.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it is a redesign on an already working device which passed the EMC certification. I have added it to the description.
The question is about the modification I want to integrate (= grouping the 5 grounds of the LEDs).

Comment: Constant currents don't generate EMI - EMI is generated by changes. This does not imply that your LED drivers are outputting constant currents.

Comment: It will also depend on your LED driver. If yours is switching on the low side (most are), this won't work and you need common Vcc instead.

Comment: Please specify the FFC cable and connectors. If you had 500mA per wire before, for each supply and return, and you combine the five returns, you have 2.5A return current in single wire.

Comment: Here is the connector : FH12-14S-0.5SH(55)
Here is the cable : 687714050002

Comment: @winny : The driver is switching on the high-side.

Comment: Good. Then you’re down to resistive losses of your shared ground and the “overhearing” of one driver to the next due to said voltage drop. If small, you won’t notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. The FFC cable would likely overheat and maybe melt or burn.

Both your connector and FFC cable are rated 500mA max.

Therefore if you have five separate 500mA constant current sources, you can't combine their return paths to a single wire, as it would mean 2.5A return current through single wire.

You have to have 5 return paths. Either separate return paths, or, if you combine the return paths on the LED board, several ground wires on the FFC is still needed, then a minimum of 5, preferably more, because if one or a few ground return wires make a bad connection, then all the return current would exceed the current carrying ability of the remaining wires.

Answer (score 0):

That is fine to combine grounds and return the current through less conductors, but that could have consequences for the LEDs if they're being switched or dimmed.

The FFC cable has resistance and will create a small voltage, the more current you send through it the more the voltage.

For example: if you have an FFC cable resistance of 100 millohm and a current of 500 mA, you will have a 50 mV voltage rise on the ground. That is probably not going to be noticeable for most applications but if you went up to more of an amp it would be 100 mV and a sizeable portion of the LED voltage which would be noticeable on most LEDs.

If combining ground conductors you might experience cross-dimming if the LEDs are being turned on and off. Measure or calculate what the resistance is and how much current you are sending through the cable and see if it will be a problem.

Combining grounds is worse for common mode voltage also, and this could cause the LED PCB to radiate. If you are using non constant currents, or PWM combining grounds could be an issue from an increase in common mode noise

Comment: I must say I do not completely agree with your argumentation. The drivers are constant current so the important parameter here is not the LED forward voltage, but rather the voltage range of the LED drivers (which is normally quite wide). One could argue that you could notice that in transients, but I (guess) it would be just too fast to be noticeable.

Comment: It won't be noticable if you never make large changes on any led, if you do make a large change on one LED, it could be a problem

Answer (score 0):

The FFC contacts are rated for current by each supplier. Not all contacts have the same area.

e.g. 1mm pitch 1.0 A